# DLL linkage error in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Recently I found a dynamic link library for my project. It can be found [here](http://pedsim.silmaril.org/). However, it is really hard for me to get it work.
What I downloaded is a .dll file and some .h headers. My IDE is Qt SDk 1.2(Qt 4.8.1).

After compling the demo code, my compiler complains that 'external linkage required for symbol 'Ped::LIBPEDSIM_VERSION' because of 'dllexport' attribute'

It is in ped_includes.h. So after some search, I added extern "C++" in the file. Now it looks like this:

```
#ifndef _ped_includes_h_
#define _ped_includes_h_ 1

#include "ped_agent.h"
#include "ped_obstacle.h"
#include "ped_waypoint.h"
#include "ped_scene.h"
extern "C++"    //what I added.
namespace Ped {
    const double LIBEXPORT LIBPEDSIM_VERSION = 2.2;
}

#endif
```

This time the error is gone and I get many '**undefined reference to XX::XX::XX()**' errors.I tried to add the path of dll into the .pro file:

```
LIBS += -LE:\\klive\\code\\QtProgram\\libpedsim-example\\libpedsim.dll
```

but it doesn't work.

Now what I want to know is whether I have modified 'ped_includes.h' correctly and what's the 
difference with and without the extern statement? Plus, how to resolve the linkage error?

Comment: Do you have the corresponding `.lib` file for the DLL?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, I have. I changed 'libpedsim.dll' into 'libpedsim.lib', still get the same errors.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Make sure not to mix MSVC and mingw-built libraries. Check that all the symbols in libpedsim are exported (dllexport, usually handle via some export macros between "class" and classname)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I'm using mingw and it seems that the dll was build by msvc since I find a .sln file in the source code I get just now.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld BTW, does LIBEXPORT equal to dllexport?

Comment: @user957121: Usually the EXPORT macro is defined to dllexport during building the library itself and dllimport when building against the library. Search for the definition of the macro to see what it does.